# No telephony feature in AVD with GSM support

Tags: android, telephony, android-virtual-device

I have added GSM support in an android emulator (AVD) but still can't find telephony feature.
I checked using few steps below :

```
boolean isTelephony = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY);
```

isTelephony is false.

```
FeatureInfo[] featureList = pm.getSystemAvailableFeatures();
```

featureList does not contain "android.hardware.telephony".

Are there any steps after add GSM support?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) - their emulators offer telephony.